# Работа с текстовым документом

Tags: python, csv

Имеется текстовый документ, который выводится листом - все, что есть внутри. Не могу понять, как мне сделать так, чтобы, просмотрев файл, был выбран какой-то определенный элемент.

Так выглядит то, что есть:

```
f = open("palgad.txt")

for line in f.readlines():
    print(line.strip().split(";")[0:])
```

А так выглядят данные внутри текстового документа:

```
Вася Пупкие;35;2500
Артем Карелин;25;1500
Влад Пуговкин;24;1400
...
(Имя Фамилия; возраст; зарплата)
```

Задание следующее: нужно, чтобы выдало имя работника, который больше всех заработал и его зарплату.

Answer (score 1):

В вашем случае удобно использовать Pandas, пример файла с данными, назовем его `data.txt`:

```
Вася Пупкие;35;2500
Артем Карелин;25;1500
Влад Пуговкин;24;1400
```

Получаем человека с самой высокой зарплатой:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('data.txt', sep=';', header=None)
data.columns = ['name', 'age', 'salary']

person = data[data['salary'] == data['salary'].max()]
```

В переменной `person` лежит нужный вам объект, и мы можем получить его имя:

```
person['name']
# Вася Пупкие
```

Соответственно можем так же получить его возраст и размер зарплаты:

```
person['age']    # 35
person['salary'] # 2500
```

Comment: Какой смысл использовать мощную и тяжёлую библиотеку, которую ещё нужно дополнительно устанавливать, если к тому коду, который уже есть у автора нужно добавить буквально пару строк? Тем более, я сильно подозреваю, что это учебное задание, и pandas будет совсем не тем, что имел в виду преподаватель.

Comment: @Александр Мощная и тяжелая ? спасибо за настроение =), ну что потяжелее стандартных я согласен, за то удобно.

Comment: Инсталлятор пандаса весит несколько мегабайт. Может быть, сейчас это и копейки, но не для задачи же, которая решается двумя строчками!

Comment: Если автору удобнее использовать условно кашу из генераторов и циклов то ради Бога, мое дело дать ответ, а он уже решить тяжелое это для него решение или нет. И вообще я считаю, что такие вещи как pandas должны быть в арсенале у каждого.

Comment: Pandas - вещь полезная, но изучать его стоит не раньше, чем изучены основы. Если автор не знает, как найти максимальный элементы в списке, то очевидно, что сначала ему нужно научиться писать простейшие циклы. А не новые библиотеки осваивать.

Answer (score 0):

Если совсем по простому:

```
def count():
    _max = {'name': '', 'sal': 0}
    with open("palgad.txt", "r") as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            our_line = line.strip().split(";")
            if int(our_line[-1]) > _max['sal']:
                _max['sal'] = int(our_line[-1])
                _max['name'] = our_line[0]
    print(_max['name'], _max['sal'])
```